# How do I know that an audio interruption ended without receiving AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded?

Tags: ios, avaudiosession

I'm using AVAudioSession in my VOIP app (using also CallKit).
I understand that the session can get interrupted by a number of things, for example by a second incoming call.
Apple states towards the bottom of this page:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH4-SW5

> "Note: There is no guarantee that a begin interruption will have a
>   corresponding end interruption. Your app needs to be aware of a switch
>   to a foreground running state or the user pressing a Play button. In
>   either case, determine whether your app should reactivate its audio
>   session."

On the mentioned page there is an example for a special case, when the user ignores the incoming call and in that case AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded is being sent.

But what should I do to know when the interruption has ended in every other case (in which cases I will never receive an AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeEnded)? (E.g. When the user answers the 2nd call and puts me on hold and later he ends the 2nd call?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I remember when you use CallKit, no app using audio like music will interrupt your app except for those other voip apps or native calls.
In that case, your call will be ended/held according to your response on the call kit ui (If your call do not support held, you will not be shown a thid button accept&hold)----Then, you can get your callback from CallKit delegate methods.

The Interruption api just works when CallKit is not used and CallKit app have a higher priority on audio session than those not using it.